# Why are some terms for relative time irregular?

Tags: words, kanji, time, irregularities-exceptions

For current time the Kanji 今{いま} for "now" can always used. Why is it that Kanji for previous (去 / 昨 / 先) and next (来 / 明) times are different and have irregular readings? In some cases it is incorrect to use the other Kanji. Is there a historical or linguistic reason for this?

> .　　year　　　　　　month　week　day　　　　night
>
> last　去年{きょねん} ／ 昨年{さくねん}　　先月{せんげつ}　先週{せんしゅう}　昨日{きのう}　　　　昨晩{さくばん} / 前夜{ぜんや}
>
> this　今年{ことし}　　　　　 今月{こんげつ}　今週{こんしゅう}　今日{きょう} / 本日{ほんじつ} 　 今晩{こんばん}
>
> next　来年{らいねん} ／ 明年{みょうねん}　来月{らいげつ}　来週{らいしゅう}　明日{あした} / 明日{あす}　　明夜{みょうや}

Comment: 本 also means "this" as in 本日、本年度、etc. Are you differentiating between this and now?

Comment: And 今's readings in its various words aren't particularly "regular"